# How get full pathfile of control input file?

Tags: php, javascript

I have got input file as:

```
<input type="file" id="txt1" onchange="setText();">
```

and script get path file as:

```
function setText()
  {
       var text = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
       alert(text);

  }
```

In textbox of input file `value= C:\Users\iloveyou\Desktop\BaiTapTest.zip`
But in script , i get value: `text=BaiTapTest.zip`
I want get `text= C:\Users\iloveyou\Desktop\BaiTapTest.zip`
Can you help me? thanks.

Comment: Imagine the fun people could have if the HR person reading your resume saw that you'd uploaded it from `c:\users\you\documents\crappy company I don't want to work for but have to because I need the money.doc`.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the full path of the file is not actually an option, due to security concerns. There are some browser-specific ways of hacking around it, but none of them are very reliable. Bottom line is, getting the full local path of a file in a predictable manner is impossible.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="file" id="txt1" onchange="javascript:alert(this.value);">​
```

is this OK for you? You can get full path by this.

[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/UB6xc/)